# Tablet as second monitor (RTMP)

Tags: multiple-monitors, vnc, rtmp

Now i am using my tablet as second monitor. My solution works likes this i've added an extra monitor virtually (by forcing use VGA) and i have served my screen with tightVNC and connected to my pc with VNC viewer actually it works pretty nice.

But i am thinking to serve my second monitor with FFsplit via RTMP and watch as stream on my tablet.

1. How can i serve RTMP directly from my PC?
2. If i able to connect via RTMP will it be faster then VNC ?

Thanks